# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 2: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python

I'm a newbie who are interested in Machine Learning using Python. So I downloaded a dataset from https://data.world/nrippner/ols-regression-challenge and tried to read the dataset using

`dataset = pd.read_csv('cancer_reg.csv')`.

But that error message came up. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

Usually these type of issues arise because of the encoding. You can try using these two parameters in combination and it should probably work. I'm using latin1 because of the `0x1f` you provide in your error.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('cancer_reg.csv',engine='python',encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('cancer_reg.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```