# Error (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte - code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')

Tags: python, visual-studio, unicode, syntax-error, python-unicode

I'm new with python. I'm trying to run this code:

```
llaves=("España","Francia","Inglaterra")
dicPaises={llaves[0]:"Madrid",llaves[1]:"Paris",llaves[2]:"Londres"}
print(dicPaises)
```

The result is the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
The thread 0x1 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\lib\runpy.py", line 242, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "C:\Users\JANSIR\source\repos\Pruebas\Pruebas.py", line 8
    llaves=("España","Francia","Inglaterra")
                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and Python 3.9.

I already tried with:
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
But it does not work.

Comment: I can run your code without problem. Did you type it with VS, or did you copy/paste it?

Comment: I type it with VS. it's really strange. Is it possible a problem with my visual studio?. And how could I solve it?

Comment: Follow  [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) and save script with `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that there is a [bug in Visual Studio 2022 using Python and UTF-8](https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/6784).

My solution was to:

- open Notepad and paste the code from the .py file into a new Notepad document.
- close the project.
- save the Notepad document with the old .py file, **but using the UTF-8 encoding**.
- open the project again.

Now the .py file is in UTF-8 and it works...

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things, the compiler is having problem with the 'ñ', because that's the character that it would probably struggle with, and **it's at position 4, which is the one highlighted by the error message**. See this answer for a similar solution:

[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 2: invalid continuation byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751700/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xf1-in-position-2-invalid)

It seems like your encoding has got mixed up. \xf1 - the byte encoding raised in the error - corresponds to 'ñ' with *latin1* encoding:

```
>>>"España".encode("latin1")
b'Espa\xf1a'
>>>b'\xf1'.decode('latin1')
'ñ'
```

Whereas *utf-8* wants to encode the ñ as a combination of a '~' and an 'n':

```
>>>b'\xc3\xb1a'.decode('utf-8')
'ñ'
```

As @JosefZ points out, you should use *utf-8* encoding always, and instead tell VS Code to use this instead of *latin1*. I think you can find the options you need here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-7.2

if you ctrl+f for "Configuring VS Code" you should find the info you need.

Comment: Yes, using a comment `coding: latin1` at the top of the code should work.

Comment: No, no, no! Stay at [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) and save script with `UTF-8` encoding.

Comment: @JosefZ good advice, but Windows makes it difficult sometimes. The key point is that the file encoding must match what is specified by the coding comment.

Comment: This answer is incorrect in one minute detail - the utf-8 representation is not two characters `~` and `n`, it's still a single character but it takes two bytes.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: The utf-8 representation for character `ñ` (U+00F1,  *Latin Small Letter N With Tilde*) is byte sequence `\xc3\xb1`. Interpreted as [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake): `Ã` (U+00C3,  *Latin Capital Letter A With Tilde*) and `±` (U+00B1,  *Plus-Minus Sign*). Characters `n` (U+006E,  *Latin Small Letter N*) and `̃` (U+0303,  *Combining Tilde*) are result of [Unicode Normalization](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/),  forms `NFD` or `NFKD`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to everyone for your replies. I fixed it finally by changing the local settings in language.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).